# In Visual Studio is it possible to see what the name of a bookmark is within the code window? (eg hovering your mouse over it to the left of the code)

Tags: visual-studio, bookmarks, usability

In Visual Studio is it possible to see what the name of a bookmark is?
Quite often I put in bookmark to remind me about a piece of code I need to get back to, then later when I do something else I come across the bookmark. (Which is often one amongst many) However if I hover the mouse over the bookmark it doesn't tell me which one it is. Can this be switched on?

Answer (score 3):

It cannot be switched on, and left-clicking in the gutter is just going to toggle a breakpoint. The closest you can get without venturing into third-party add-ons is to keep the Visual Studio Bookmarks window pinned to your workspace--or within easy reach. To open that window, hit `[Ctrl]-grave accent` and it will highlight any bookmark you navigate to using `[Ctrl]K, [Ctrl]N` or `[Ctrl]P` (next/previous bookmark) or `[Shift][Ctrl]K`, `[Shift][Ctrl]N` or `[Shift][Ctrl]P` (next/previous bookmark in the current folder).